# Separate Loop for Custom Post Type in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a guitar lessons site and I have a question about Custom Post Types. I am creating a "Lessons" page which will be my main blog / loop. I also wanted to create a custom post type for "Arrangements" which will be just video / songs I arrange and play.

I'm using CPT UI for the custom post type called "Arrangements" and I'm trying to figure out how to create separate loops - Lessons = main post type, Arrangements = custom post type.

I have a arrangements.php template that has a loop like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => array('post', 'arrangements'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$new_post_loop = new WP_Query($args);

if ($new_post_loop->have_posts()) :

    while ($new_post_loop->have_posts()) :

        $new_post_loop->the_post();

        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'blog');

    endwhile;

    the_posts_navigation();

else :

    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none');

endif;
?>
```

However, it's pulling in all of my Lessons as well as the custom post type. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Where you are trying to execute this loop logic in an archive or a single page. Here is the template hierarchy https://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: On a single page. I have a template file called arrangements.php, and within the Wordpress dashboard, I assigned that template as the page Attribute. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Then try like this `single-arrangements.php`

Comment: So I set the page template to "default template" and changed the name of my file to single-arrangements.php, and moved it out of my templates folder so it's in the root theme folder. Now nothing is displaying. Would I need to change the above code? Thanks!

Comment: Try to debug and found what template the current empty page is rendering, more details available here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have one custom post type called `arrangements` and you're using the default post as your lessons.

You're asking the `query` to display your two posts types. That's why you're getting back both of them `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'arrangements' ) ...`

You need to create **two different query**, each of them looping through one of your posts types.

There is multiple ways to do it. Here is an example.

```
<?php
$types = [  // define each of your post types in an array
  'post',
  'arrangements',
];

foreach ( $types as $type ): // for each one of our post types under the array $types

  $args = [
    'post_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    // maybe add other arguments @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
  ];

  $query = new WP_Query( $args ); // create a new query

  if( $query->have_posts() ): // if our new query as posts then...

    echo "<h1>" . $type . "</h1>";

    $i = 0; // set a variable as i = 0 to count post in the loop

    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); // while we are display a post and reapeat

      $i++; // for each post count 1

      if( $i > 1 ) // if more than one post then...
        echo "<hr>";

      if( ! empty( get_the_title() ) ) // if our title isn't empty then...
        esc_attr( the_title( '<h4>', '</h4>' ) );

      if( ! empty( get_the_content() ) ) // if our content isn't empty then...
        esc_attr( the_content() );

    endwhile;

  else: // if our new query has no posts then...

    echo "<h1><s>" . $type . "</s></h1>";

  endif;

  wp_reset_postdata(); // MUST reset post data to prevent any trouble shoot for our next query request

endforeach; ?>
```

You could also just do two different queries one with `'post_type' => 'arrangements'` and one with `'post_type' => 'post'`. Both method gives you the same result.

---

### Learn more

- `WP_Query` Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
- `wp_reset_postdata()` Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/